# Django Custom template tag & getting pk from database

Tags: django

I have a user profile model with user(ForeignKey) and user_timezone(CharField). On my template page there's a drop down box that lets the user select their timezone, they submit and everything works fine. Except for the fact that I have to hard code the pk. I can't seem to figure out how to get the current user?

```
import pytz
import datetime
import time
from pytz import timezone
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from turnover.models import UserProfile
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

register = template.Library()

class TimeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, format_string):
        self.format_string = format_string

    def render(self, context):
        # Get the user profile and their timezone
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=99) #<------ Hard Coded--
        set_user_timezone = profile.user_timezone

        # Set the Timezone
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time(), pytz.utc)
        get_timezone = pytz.timezone(u'%s' % set_user_timezone)
        profile_timezone = get_timezone.normalize(dt.astimezone(get_timezone)).strftime(self.format_string)
        return profile_timezone

    @register.tag(name="current_time")
    def current_time(parser, token):
        tag_name, format_string = token.split_contents()
        return TimeNode(format_string[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
request = context.get('request')
user = request.user
```

But you should have in settings:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...
)
```

Comment: That was it, I was not sure how to pass request. After 2 days of trying everything under then sun it was 2 short lines of code. Less is more.

Answer (score 0):

```
class TimeNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, format_string, user):
        self.format_string = format_string
        self.user = template.Variable(user)

    def render(self, context):
        # Get the user profile and their timezone
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=self.user) #<------ Hard Coded--
        set_user_timezone = profile.user_timezone

        # Set the Timezone
        dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time(), pytz.utc)
        get_timezone = pytz.timezone(u'%s' % set_user_timezone)
        profile_timezone = get_timezone.normalize(dt.astimezone(get_timezone)).strftime(self.format_string)
        return profile_timezone

    @register.tag(name="current_time")
    def current_time(parser, token):
        tag_name, format_string, user = token.split_contents()
        return TimeNode(format_string[1:-1], user)
```

then you can do something like

`{% current_time "timestring" request.user %}`